# Getting JSON format error in Logstash. Need to decode JSON from the message part

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, gsub, mutate

I am using the below code in my logstash but the message field is coming after getting converted into JSON twice, but I need the message with a single JSON format, how can I decode it from JSON one step back:

```
file {
        id => "my_lt_log"
        path => "/logs/logtransformer.log"
        type => "log"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
}
filter {
if [type] == "log" {
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "kubernetes"]
        }
        mutate {
          gsub => [ "message", "(\W)at(\W)", '\1""\2' ]
        }
        if [message][metadata][proc_id] {
            mutate {
              add_field => { "[metadata][proc_id]" => "%{[message][metadata][proc_id]}" }
            }
            }
        if "_jsonparsefailure" in [tags] {
          mutate {
            add_field => {
              "logplane" => "adp-app-logs"
              "abc" => "%{[message]}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "message", "kubernetes" ]
          }
        }
        else {
          mutate {
              rename => {
                "path" => "filename"
              }
              add_field => {
                "def" => "%{[message]}"
                
                "message" => "%{[message][message]}"
                "timestamp" => "%{[message][timestamp]}"
              }
            }
            
      }
}
output {
...
}
```

Output:

```
{
        "_index" : "adp-app-logs-2023.02.03",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PpiDF4YBCMtUNdxoMJFW",
        "_score" : 0.79323065,
        "_source" : {
          "@version" : "1",
          "service_id" : "%{[message][service_id]}",
          "def" : "{\"version\": \"1.1.0\", \"timestamp\": \"2023-02-03T13:41:43.034Z\", \"severity\": \"info\", \"service_id\": \"eric-log-transformer\", \"metadata\" : {\"namespace\": \"zyadros\", \"pod_name\": \"eric-log-transformer-7b64896976-s6h5r\", \"node_name\": \"node-10-63-142-135\", \"pod_uid\": \"336c9706-41a9-41c0-b459-2eb4e9f6e2b4\", \"container_name\": \"logtransformer\"}, \"message\": \"Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>'opensearch', 'pipeline.workers'=>2, 'pipeline.batch.size'=>2048, 'pipeline.batch.delay'=>50, 'pipeline.max_inflight'=>4096, 'pipeline.sources'=>['/opt/logstash/resource/searchengine.conf'], :thread=>'#<Thread:0x7649ae47 run>'}\"}",
          "@timestamp" : "2023-02-03T13:41:58.044976Z",
          "severity" : "%{[message][severity]}"
        }
      }
```

Expected Output for the field 'def':

```
{"version": "1.1.0", "timestamp": "2023-02-06T06:18:33.647Z", "severity": "info", "service_id": "eric-log-transformer", "metadata" : {"namespace": "zyadros", "pod_name": "eric-log-transformer-5cb7dbc6b5-ghrsc", "node_name": "node-10-63-142-135", "pod_uid": "52b8e6fe-9547-4091-9034-36e1141f4391", "container_name": "logtransformer"}, "message": "Starting tcp input listener {:address=>'0.0.0.0:5015', :ssl_enable=>true}"}
```

Input file sample:

```
{"version": "1.1.0", "timestamp": "2023-02-06T13:42:59.634Z", "severity": "info", "service_id": "eric-log-transformer", "metadata" : {"namespace": "roshan", "pod_name": "eric-log-transformer-5bc84c4cb-c8qtw", "node_name": "node-10-63-142-135", "pod_uid": "00632d7b-d151-4b0c-84fe-8a6ee6b64b35", "container_name": "logtransformer"}, "message": "Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>'logstash', 'pipeline.workers'=>2, 'pipeline.batch.size'=>2048, 'pipeline.batch.delay'=>50, 'pipeline.max_inflight'=>4096, 'pipeline.sources'=>['/opt/logstash/resource/logstash.conf'], :thread=>'#<Thread:0x3d8b1518 run>'}"}
```

Getting the below Error while adding json {source}:

```
{
        "_index" : "%{logplane}-2023.02.07",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9d6xKoYBCoUR1nQuuhlp",
        "_score" : 2.969562E-4,
        "_source" : {
          "path" : "/logs/logtransformer.log",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "_jsonparsefailure"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2023-02-07T07:05:22.465556Z",
          "host" : "eric-log-transformer-d6dddd6f9-lp6d7",
          "message" : " at [Source: (byte[])' at [Source: (byte[])' at [Source: (byte[])'{'version': '1.1.0', 'timestamp': '2023-02-07T07:05:06.163Z', 'severity': 'warning', 'service_id': 'eric-log-transformer', 'metadata' : {'namespace': 'zyadros', 'pod_name': 'eric-log-transformer-d6dddd6f9-lp6d7', 'node_name': 'node-10-63-142-138', 'pod_uid': '02659e5c-c9ac-49c8-a4bd-74b9477e846d', 'container_name': 'logtransformer'}, 'message': 'Error parsing json {:source=>'message', :raw=>'{\\'version\\': \\'1.1.0\\', \\'timestamp\\': \\'2023-02-07T07:05:02'[truncated 68 bytes]; line: 1, column: 5]>}\"}"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Can you please provide input file sample.

Comment: You're neither using any `json` codec nor the `json` filter to parse your message field. How can you expect the event to be tagged with `_jsonparsefailure` ?

Comment: Yes correct but i tried that codec part earlier, so I added the json failure part...

Comment: And what didn't work out with the `json` codec?

Comment: @Val it gave Error Parsing JSON.

Comment: @SagarPatel added in the question, input file sample.

Comment: @Val added the input file, please check

Comment: Can you show the parsing error you got before?

Comment: @Val It was a huge error log with multiple \ in between.

Comment: That doesn't tell me much unfortunately... Try to reproduce it and share it, we might learn something